# is it possible to restrict access to GCS bucket from GCP load balancer only?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-load-balancer

I've successfully deployed a static website on a Google Cloud Storage bucket and configured it as the backend for an external application load balancer within Google Cloud Platform. I'm now seeking a way to restrict access to the GCS bucket, allowing only the GCP load balancer to reach it.

Comment: Add Cloud CDN to the load balancer. See this [link](https://cloud.google.com/cdn/docs/using-signed-cookies#configure_permissions). Think about why you want to limit access and require the user to go through a load balancer. That will decrease performance (in some cases - cache refresh, etc) and increase costs. Cloud Storage is highly performant and fault tolerant. There are times when using Cloud CDN is a good idea, just make sure you have reviewed the options.

Answer (score 1):

**I agreed with what @JohnHanley said.**

Consider your reasons for wanting to restrict access and have the user go through a load balancer. That will raise expenses and potentially reduce performance (cache refresh, etc.).

Cloud storage is extremely reliable and resistant to errors. Sometimes it makes sense to use Cloud CDN just make sure you've looked over your choices.

**As per this official [doc](https://cloud.google.com/cdn/docs/using-signed-cookies#configure_permissions)**

You must add the Cloud CDN service account to Cloud Storage ACLs in order to grant Cloud CDN permission to read the objects if you utilize Cloud Storage and have restricted who can read them.

The creation of the service account is not required. When you add a key to a backend bucket in a project for the first time, the service account is automatically established.

Refer to this official [doc](https://cloud.google.com/cdn/pricing) for  cloud CDN Pricing

you can also use [media cdn](https://cloud.google.com/media-cdn/docs/origins?hl=en#private-storage-buckets) to prevent unauthorized access

For more information refer to this [gitlink](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/community/blob/master/archived/securing-gcs-static-website/index.md)

Comment: @BTS  If the bucket is set to public you  have to follow one of these  see this [stack link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70617911/18265570)

Comment: @BTS May I know what is your requirement? Whom do  you want to restrict accessing GCS? do you want to restrict any domain? If you provide additional information, I can modify my answer accordingly

Comment: I'm seeking to safeguard my static website using Cloud Armor. If the bucket is publicly accessible, can users still bypass protection and directly access files via the GCS URL (https://storage.googleapis.com/my-bucket)? Does Cloud CDN offer measures to prevent such direct access?"

Comment: You  can follow the Backend Security Policy mentioned in this  [Stack link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74983941/18265570) by Dave  for cloud armor against cloud storage.

Comment: Once the image/file has been set to public, any random user/website with the URL can read or download the file.to avoid that you can use ACL  to follow this [stack link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74323206) by Veera nagireddy